# Google Earth Pro - Automatically load a secondary database

Tags: google-earth-pro

Is it possible to configure Google Earth Pro so that it automatically loads a secondary database (e.g QLD Globe) when starting up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to automate this is to save the qldglobe.kml from https://www.business.qld.gov.au/business/support-tools-grants/services/mapping-data-imagery/queensland-globe/install-mac-pc onto your desktop.

Then assuming that you have the file association for *.kml files set to Google Earth Pro then double-clicking on the Queensland Globe icon on your desktop should start Google Earth Pro with the Qld Globe installed.

Comment: As an aside, if you are new to Qld Globe, then there is an eLearning video tutorial (currently US$14) about it that I wrote and recorded available from http://discoverspatial.com/courses/qld-globe

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I have found that I could not get earth pro to load another data base like globe kml NSW QLD etc. So to fix the prob I had to uninstall pro and revert to just earth.